# ConEnu: How do you set a tab to be active within mutltipe tabs?

Tags: conemu

I'm trying to create a Task in ConEmu to open 5 consoles.
The first 4 consoles will split a tab to 4 panes. 
The fifth consoles will be opened in a new tab.

How do you set the fifth console's tab to be active?
Thanks.

My Task file

```
set "PATH=%ProgramFiles%\Git\usr\bin;%PATH%" & "%ProgramFiles%\Git\git-cmd.exe" --no-cd --command=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-msys2-64.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i -cur_console:d:c:\a


set "PATH=%ProgramFiles%\Git\usr\bin;%PATH%" & "%ProgramFiles%\Git\git-cmd.exe" --no-cd --command=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-msys2-64.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i -cur_console:fs1T50H  -cur_console:d:C:\b


set "PATH=%ProgramFiles%\Git\usr\bin;%PATH%" & "%ProgramFiles%\Git\git-cmd.exe" --no-cd --command=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-msys2-64.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i -cur_console:fs2TV -cur_console:d:C:\c

set "PATH=%ProgramFiles%\Git\usr\bin;%PATH%" & "%ProgramFiles%\Git\git-cmd.exe" --no-cd --command=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-msys2-64.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i -cur_console:bs1T50V    -cur_console:d:C:\d


* -new_console:f -cur_console:f cmd.exe /k "%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified switch `f` for the second console